# Hermitian inner product and basis change

Tags: linear-algebra

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222196/matrix-of-a-hermitian-metric-for-two-different-basis) has the following set up

> Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of a $\mathbb{C}$-linear space $E$ and $h$ a Hermitian metric on $E$. Denote by $H=\{h_{ij}\}$ the matrix of $h$ for $\{e_i\}$, that is
> $$h_{ij}=h(e_i,e_j).$$
> Let now $g\in GL(E)$ be a complex automorphism and consider the new basis $\{e'_i\}=\{ge_i\}$. Denote by $H'=\{h'_{ij}\}$ the corresponding matrix. What is the relation between $H$ and $H'$?

The answers give two different results for this and I've been trying to figure out if they are the same or is there something else going on.

The accepted answer states that

$$
H' = g^\ast H g
$$

and the latter one that

$$
H'=g^TH\bar{g}. 
$$

If we consider $v,u \in H$ with $v=v^1e_1+\dots+v^ne_n$ and $u=u^1e_1+\dots+u^ne_n$, then $$h(u,v)=u^ih(e_i,e_j)\bar{v}^j = \begin{bmatrix}u\end{bmatrix}^TH\begin{bmatrix}\bar{v}\end{bmatrix}$$

which would seem like more like the latter one?

Comment: It is a matter of convention whether the left-hand argument or the right-hand argument is conjugated. I believe that mathematicians and physicists typically choose different convention. That may be your issue, different conventions yield different solutions. Personally, it fits my mental model better to conjugate the left-hand argument (as physicians do I believe), because you can consider that a dual vector (on the left) acts on a vector (on the right). But it is ultimately a matter of taste or habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of lisibility, $G$ is written instead of $g$. For a scalar
$a$, $\bar{a}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $a$. Also,
$\overline{G}$ is defined such that
$\overline{G}_{i,j} = \overline{G_{i,j}}$ (conjugation only), whereas
$G^\ast$ is defined such that $G^{\ast}_{i,j} = \overline{G_{j,i}}$
(conjugation and transposition).

If $h(., .)$ is linear in the first argument (scalar product following
the convention in mathematics):
$$\begin{align}
    H'_{i,j}
 &= h(G e_i, G e_j)                                            \\
 &= h(\sum_k G_{k,i} \cdot e_k, \sum_l G_{l,j} \cdot e_l)      \\
 &= \sum_{k,l} G_{k,i} \cdot H_{k,l} \cdot \overline{G_{l,j}}  \\
 &= (G ^T H \overline{G})_{i,j}
\end{align}$$

If $h(., .)$ is linear in the second argument (scalar product following
the convention in physics):
$$\begin{align}
    H'_{i,j}
 &= h(G e_i, G e_j)                                            \\
 &= h(\sum_k G_{k,i} \cdot e_k, \sum_l G_{l,j} \cdot e_l)      \\
 &= \sum_{k,l} \overline{G_{k,i}} \cdot H_{k,l} \cdot G_{l,j}  \\
 &= (G^\ast H G)_{i,j}
\end{align}$$